# What are the difference between the options in the drop down menu beside sign in option?

Tags: login-screen

In the log in screen there is a small settings icons beside 'sign in'. There are some options in there including 'ubuntu', 'gnome' etc. I am familliar with these but what's the significance of choosing one of them there?

Comment: That's how you choose the desktop environment. Try a different choice and see for yourself.

Comment: why not pick one and see for yourself? Oh and those are the available desktops ;)

Comment: I tried actually and I felt a few difference in here and there. I revert back as I though if my customizations get lost anyhow. So exploring is safe? I mean will they override or oerwrite any settings?

Comment: If you pick one desktop and don't like it go back to the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the options are for choosing between types of desktop environment and display servers.

If you have more than one desktop environment installed on your system, you would be able to choose one of them. Some examples for desktop environments are: Gnome, Cinnamon, Unity,Xfce, KDE and MATE.Main difference between desktop environments are the look of them and the amount of resources(RAM) they use.

if you have more than one display server installed on your system, you would be able to choose one of them. Some examples for display servers are Wayland and Xorg. Some programs may have problem running on some display servers.
And also Ubuntu is the name of GNU/Linux distribution you are using.

To know more about display servers you can visit [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server).
To know more about desktop environments you can visit [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment).